# DNS reverse query

Tags: dns

When I do reverse DNS queries with IP address that I obtained from DNS query of one website, it shows many different domain names, why is it so? I thought if I do the reverse DNS query I will obtain the domain name which I did with just DNS query. Reverse DNS doesn't work correct or all those names are correct? I don't understand

Comment: See https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/bro-pdns-forward-dns for a way to have the reverse lookup give you the last name you have resolved to that IP address.

Answer (score 2):

The mapping between an IP address and a domain name isn't one-to-one. You can have any number of (possibly completely unrelated) domain names pointing to the same IP address. (And conversely, a given domain name can resolve to several different IP addresses.)

This is perfectly normal, and quite usual.

Comment: Thank you but why it can have any number of domain names pointing the same IP address? I still don't get that

Comment: Because it's very practical. Needing one separate IP address for each and every website out there would be a pain (think hosting sites, VPS, blog platforms and such). Would be a waste of IPv4 space too.

Comment: A reverse DNS query normally returns no more than **one** PTR record, regardless of the number of A records pointing to the host.

Answer (score 1):

Because the hosting provider uses [virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting). With one/several server/s using a web server like Apache is able to handle many domains with one public IP. As you may know, with the imminent exhaustion of the central pool of IPv4 addresses, any public IP is a great asset.